# Chrome Experimental Socket API: What Does `chrome.experimental.socket.sendTo()` And `recvFrom()` Do?

Tags: sockets, google-chrome, tcp, google-chrome-extension, chromium

This week, I messed around with Chromium's Socket API a bit. But there's something which isn't really clear to me about this bad documented experimental interface.

### What The [docs](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/trunk/experimental.socket.html) on Google Code Say:

... about `sendTo()` at the moment:

> Writes data on the given socket.
>
> 1. ***`socketId ( integer )`*** The socketId.
> 2. ***`data ( ArrayBuffer )`*** The data to
>      write.
> 3. ***`address ( string )`***
>      The address of the remote machine.
> 4. ***`port (
>      integer )`*** The port of the remote machine.
> 5. ***`SendToCallback ( function
>          )`***

But the description of `sendTo()` is exactly the same as the description of `write()` (*`write` - Writes data on the given socket.*). It's the same about `recvFrom()` and `read()` - both of them have got exactly the same description (*`read` - Reads data from the given socket.* / *`recvFrom` - Reads data from the given socket.*). But nobody says interesting anything about the **differences**.

### What I Found Out:

It doesn't matter what I'm doing, `sendTo` always returns the following object:

> - **[-]** *Object*
>
>   - `bytesWritten`: `-2`
>   - **[+]** `__proto__`: *Object*

If I use `write` instead of `sendTo` in all these situations, everything happens as expected.

It's the same with `recvFrom()` and `read()` - `read()` is working as expected and `recvFrom()` fails.

### My Question(s):

- What is `sendTo()` for and what's the difference between `write()`
  and `sendTo()`?
- What is `recvFrom()` for and what's the difference between `read()` and `recvFrom()`?
- Why are there so many akin methods?
- **And:** Is there anywhere some **more information** about the Socket API? The Google Code docs are really lightweight. Aren't there any articles on `chromium.org` concerning that?

Thanks.

Comment: My best guess is that `sendTo` is for use with sockets that have not participated in a `connect` operation.  Does `sendTo` work if you do not `connect` the socket?

Comment: @apsillers I did some trials concerning that and the only situation when `sendTo` worked was when I applied that method on a bound UDP socket. I can't find any information about that on Google Code or `chrome.org`, but I think that there isn't any use case for `sendTo` on TCP sockets at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apologies for the confusion. We are rolling out an [improvement to the documentation](https://chromiumcodereview.appspot.com/10796067/) based on your question.

The Chrome socket API is a thin layer over a subset of the POSIX sockets API. It follows the convention that read()/write() are for connected sockets, and sendto()/recvfrom() are for non-connected sockets. At the risk of oversimplifying, you'll want to use the former for connected-oriented protocols (TCP), and the latter for connectionless protocols (UDP). There's a good comparison of why one would choose TCP vs. UDP in the [Wikipedia article on UDP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol#Comparison_of_UDP_and_TCP).

Comment: Thanks. Just one question concerning that: Why are the TCP method names different to the UDP method names? Is there a special reason or did you just take the names from POSIX?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about sockets but I think the docs are mixed up, and sendTo is used when a connection is being initiated from the browser (or the other way around maybe, and the other should be used when a client initiates a socket connection into the browser but I don't see any SocketServer support anywhere so... anyway). From [source](http://code.google.com/codesearch#wZuuyuB8jKQ/chromium/src/chrome/common/extensions/api/experimental_socket.idl&q=SendToCallback&type=cs) (check out the parameters):

- **write()**

  ```
    // Writes data on the given socket.
    // |socketId| : The socketId.
    // |data| : The data to write.
    // |callback| : Called when the first of any of the following happens: the
    // write operation completes without blocking, the write operation blocked
    // before completion (in which case onEvent() will eventually be called with
    // a <code>writeComplete</code> event), or an error occurred.
    static void write(long socketId,
                      ArrayBuffer data,
                      WriteCallback callback);
  ```
- **sendTo()**

  ```
    // Writes data on the given socket.
    // |socketId| : The socketId.
    // |data| : The data to write.
    // |address| : The address of the remote machine.
    // |port| : The port of the remote machine.
    // |callback| : Called when the first of any of the following happens: the
    // write operation completes without blocking, the write operation blocked
    // before completion (in which case onEvent() will eventually be called with
    // a <code>writeComplete</code> event), or an error occurred.
    static void sendTo(long socketId,
                       ArrayBuffer data,
                       DOMString address,
                       long port,
                       SendToCallback callback);
  ```

You have the rest of the documentation in the link I gave you (experimental_socket.idl).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Everything I tried out until now speaks in the favor of your assumption. So I think `recvFrom()`/`sendTo()` is inoperable for TCP sockets at the moment.